# How to make a horizontal border with circles on each end

Tags: html, css, border

I need to make a border like this image

[image: http://i.imgur.com/sFVUTrk.jpg]

Anyone have an idea to make it?
I tried with :after and :before attributes of css but with no sucess.
The html tag is a h1 that needs that kind of border on the bottom. Is it possible to make it?

Comment: That is not a css border.  That is an image.  I'd love to see the answer that gives you a css-only way to accomplish it, because I don't think it's possible...

Comment: Look into the CSS property called `border-radius`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

pseudo-elements!

```
div {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black; 
    padding-bottom: 15px; 
    position: relative;
}

div:before, 
div:after {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -6px; 
    left: 0; 
    height: 10px; 
    width: 10px; 
    background: black; 
    content: ""; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}

div:after {
    right: 0; 
    left: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GVb59/

Comment: +1 - Nice, that's awesome.  What sort of browser support does this have?

Comment: browser support: http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent (for the circles to appear) and http://caniuse.com/border-radius (for the circles to look like circles, not squares)

Comment: How would I will be able to add triangle in the middle?

Comment: You could also use 3 elements side by side.  So two circles using border-radius and a single line between using a border.   But I like this solution better.